# SQL запрос для сообщений

Tags: sql

Как выбрать последние входящие на исходящие сообщения пользователя?

Есть таблица сообщений. поля такие: 
id, sender, recipient, message, date, read.

Нужно выбрать такие сообщения где `('sender' = my_user_id and 'recipient' = friend_id) or ('recipient' = my_user_id and 'sender' = friend_id)`, при этом я должен получить все поля таблицы и все последние сообщения (уникальные, то есть по одному сообщению на каждого друга)

Comment: А что такое firend_id, откуда он берется. И какой именно диалект SQL. В разных СУБД подходы к решению отличаются. Вот, что то похожее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/496532#496532 для mysql

Comment: действительно я сам запутался и не правильно сформировал вопрос. friend_id - его в данном случае не нужно, просто нужно как то сделать так, чтоб не было дублей, то есть 'sender' = my_user_id OR 'recipient' = my_user_id, но чтоб не тянуть 2 записи где например (sender = my_user_id , recipient = 56) и (sender = 56, recipient = my_user_id ) - это будут входящие и исходящие сообщения с тем же самим юзером, а мне нужно только одно сообщение (последнее\)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для СУБД поддерживающих оконные функции, т.е. MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress:

```
select * from (
  select M.*,
         row_number() over(
          partition by case sender when MY_USER_ID then recipient else sender end
          order by date desc
         ) N
    from mailTable M
   where MY_USER_ID in(sender,recipient)
) A where N=1
```

Для MySQL:

```
select * from (
  select M.*,
         @n:=if(@lid=if(sender=MY_USER_ID,recipient,sender),@n+1,1) N,
         @lid:=if(sender=MY_USER_ID,recipient,sender)
    from mailTable M,(select @lid:=NULL,@n:=0) A
   where MY_USER_ID in(sender,recipient)
   order by if(sender=MY_USER_ID,recipient,sender),date desc
) A where N=1
```

Общий вариант, скорее всего более медленный (работоспособность не тестировал):

```
select * from mailTable M
 where (sender=MY_USER_ID or recipient=MY_USER_ID)
   and not exists(
        select 1 from mailTable X
         where (  (X.sender=M.sender and X.recipient=M.recipient)
               or (X.sender=M.recipient and X.recipient=M.sender) )
           and X.date > M.date
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked a little

```
SELECT r.id
      ,r.type
      ,r.name
      ,rm.text
      ,rmf.file
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN room_participants rp
    on r.id = rp.room_id
INNER JOIN
(
      SELECT room_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
      FROM room_messages
      GROUP BY room_id
) rm_max
    ON r.id = rm_max.room_id
INNER JOIN room_messages rm
    ON r.id = rm.room_id AND rm_max.max_id = rm.id
LEFT JOIN room_message_files rmf
    ON rm.id = rmf.room_message_id
where rp."participantType" = 'USER' and rp.participant_id = 1
ORDER BY rm.room_id;
```