# Извлечь второй параметр в запросе с max

Tags: sql

Есть запрос который находит максимальный тираж выпускаемых газет, он работает:

```
  SELECT MAX(SUM(COUNT)) 
    FROM DELIVERY, 
         NEWSPAPER 
   WHERE DELIVERY.IDNEWSPAPERKEY=NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER 
GROUP BY NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER
```

Мне нужно вытянуть второй параметр, например ID газеты имеющей максимальный тираж, если я добавлю еще один параметр как в запросе ниже:

```
  SELECT IDNEWSPAPER, 
         MAX(SUM(COUNT)) 
    FROM DELIVERY, 
         NEWSPAPER 
   WHERE DELIVERY.IDNEWSPAPERKEY=NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER 
GROUP BY NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER
```

вылетает ошибка:

```
not a single-group group function
```

Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Решение проблемы описано здесь
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795198/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function

Comment: Как вариант, вторая часть ответа http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/496532#496532 имена функций работы со строками подправить под ваш диалект SQL

Answer (score 2):

1. Непонятно, почему работает первый запрос, и что он выводит.
2. Если вы ищете максимум по ID, то какой ID вы хотите увидеть?
   Пока так:

```
SELECT IDNEWSPAPER,
         SUM(COUNT)
    FROM DELIVERY, 
         NEWSPAPER 
   WHERE DELIVERY.IDNEWSPAPERKEY=NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER 
GROUP BY NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER
having          SUM(COUNT) >=
ALL(SELECT         SUM(COUNT)
    FROM DELIVERY, 
         NEWSPAPER 
   WHERE DELIVERY.IDNEWSPAPERKEY=NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER 
GROUP BY NEWSPAPER.IDNEWSPAPER
);
```