# Добавить в sql запрос LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, MAX(p.date) as date
FROM (
    SELECT id, user_id, date
    FROM pm
    WHERE useru_id = 2

    UNION

    SELECT id, useru_id, date
    FROM pm
    WHERE user_id = 2
    ORDER BY date DESC) as p
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Этот запрос выводит список всех диалогов пользователя №2 (вроде работает нормально). В этот запрос нужно вставить `LEFT JOIN` к таблице `users`, чтобы вытащить о пользователе информацию. Прошу помощи в этом. Если нужно дамп таблицы с сообщениями - выложу.

Comment: у вас на `group by` не ругается? вы не указали `p.id` в `GROUP BY`. И да - вопрос непонятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного переработал запрос, что бы по таблице pm один раз бежал. И выбросил поле pm.id из выборки, потому как оно приобретало абсолютно непредсказуемое значение т.к. оно не входило ни в group by, ни было обернуто групповой функцией типа min/max.

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.date, u.*
 FROM (
       SELECT IF(useru_id=2,user_id,useru_id) as user_id, MAX(date) as date
         FROM pm
        WHERE useru_id = 2 OR user_id = 2
        GROUP BY IF(useru_id=2,user_id,useru_id)
      ) as p
 LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id=p.user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Comment: почему то уходит в ошибку если в SELECT добавить другие столбцы таблицы pm

Comment: @skillful А вы эти столбцы в GROUP BY добавляете ? По хорошему вы без групповых функций можете выбирать только те столбцы которые участвуют в group by. Либо надо применять к самим столбцам групповые функции т.е. решить какое из значений максимальное или минимальное вам необходимо. Если же вы хотите выбрать значения других столбцов именно для записей с максимальной датой - то это вообще отдельный вопрос. Рассмотренный например здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/496532#496532

Comment: еще раз спасибо!!