# MySQL: Join двух таблиц (отношение один ко многим)

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Нужно сделать `Join` двух таблиц (отношение один ко многим).
Тут все отлично, но у меня появилось 2 записи для одного домена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе тоже не сложно

```
GROUP BY `name`
```

Но

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно после группировки он оставил первое значение, а мне нужно оставить последнее, а лучше всего есть поле `date` по нему оставлять то у которого самая свежая дата

```
SELECT
`domain`.`id` AS `id`,
`domain`.`dns_a` AS `dns_a`,
`domain`.`name` AS `name`,
`domain_info`.`keywords` AS `keywords`,
`domain_info`.`keywords_dynamic` AS `keywords_dynamic`,
`domain_info`.`date` AS `date`,
`domain_info`.`se` AS `se`,
`domain`.`published` AS `published`
FROM
(
    domain
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `domain_info` ON (
        (
            domain.id = `domain_info`.domain_id
        )
    )
)
GROUP BY `name`
```

Пробовал через `WHERE` и  `HAVING` — получилось, но тогда он не оставляет те строки в которых есть домен, но еще нету статистики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас стандартная задача поиска последних по дате записей, немного обремененная тем, что данная выборка нужна из второй таблицы в join. Есть несколько подходов, какой из них быстрее работает зависит от множества факторов, таких как количество записей в обоих таблицах, количество записей отбираемых по условиям данного запроса и прочих.

Если в таблице domain_info есть первичный ключ (предположим с именем dominfo_id), то можно попробовать такое решение:

```
SELECT
       ...
  FROM domain A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `domain_info` B
    ON B.dominfo_id=
       (
        select dominfo_id
          from domain_info C
         where A.id = C.domain_id
         order by date desc
         limit 1
       )
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f46/1/0)

Если первичного ключа нет, то подзапрос должен вернуть саму максимальную дату, а условие ON будет выглядеть как то так `ON A.id=B.domain_id and B.date = (select max(date) ...)`

Так же можно попробовать один их подходов описанных [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/496532#496532).

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b876a/5
Но он тоже почему-то не так работает + не оставляет пустые ряды вообще... или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: @MaximusFT Во первых вы зачем то написали функцию max() которая без group by собирала все до одной строки. Во вторых, у вас во второй таблице не объявлен первичный ключ. В ней должен быть как id домена, который может повторятся, так и собственный первичный ключ, который повторятся разумеется не может (на то он и первичный). Получается так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f46/1/0

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно указать при выборке max(date) и выполнить группировку. Тогда при группировке будет выбираться максимальное для данной группы значение по дате. Если же будет null, он так и останется null. То есть все домены попадут в список.
Вот так [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1beec/4)

```
select domain.name, max(domain_info.date) 
from domain
left join domain_info on domain.id = domain_info.domain_id
group by domain.name;
```

Comment: добавил колонку в ваш пример VIS и вот что получилось
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b876a/3
Дата приходит правильно, но колонка VIS не из той строки...

Есть мысли?