# MySQL: ORDER BY перед GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

такая ситуация:
есть две таблицы: одна с товарами, другая таблица с ценами на них у поставщиков, т.е. для одного товара в таблице №1 есть несколько записей во таблице №2 с ценой и наличием.

пытаюсь сделать запрос, который бы вывел товары, а также его минимальную цену и максимальное наличие.

т.е. есть:
table1.item_id = товар
и
table2.item_id = товар
table2.item_price = цена
table2.item_avail = наличие

цена и наличие числовые поля, чем выше значение в наличии, тем приоритетнее должен быть результат.

я делаю объединение двух этих таблиц, сортирую по наличию и цене, затем группирую по item_id. Но по факту группировка происходит раньше чем сортировка.

запрос такой:

```
SELECT `item_id`, `item_price`, `item_avail`

FROM (
    SELECT  *        
    FROM `items` as `table1`
    LEFT JOIN(            
        SELECT * FROM `prices`
        GROUP BY `item_id`
        ORDER BY`item_available` DESC,  `item_price` ASC        
    ) as `table2` on `table2`.`item_id` = `table1`.`item_id`
) as `table1`
```

соответственно получается что в сортировке уже участвует только одна запись из таблицы 2.
подскажите, как можно сделать сортировку, перед группировкой?

Comment: Ваш самый внутренний запрос имеет **неопределённый** результат и работает только потому, что MySQL в нестрогом режиме. Сортировка не гарантирует, что выведется то что вам надо.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду? без группировки сортировка работает верно, а вот вместе с группировкой как я понял из документации, сначала срабатывает группировка, а потом уже сортировка - что приводите к не тому результату что я ожидал. Как сделать наоборот, я не могу найти информации...

Comment: Пусть в prices 4 записи (товар, цена): 1,5; 1,10; 2,4; 2,11 на выходе после группировки по товару у нас будут две записи 1 и 2 их поле "цена" не определена, потому как мы не сказали MySQL какая именно  цена из двух нас интересует. в этом примере какой из товаров должен быть первым и почему

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql/599802#599802

Comment: понятно что цена однозначно не определена, т.к. есть два варианта цены. Поэтому я делаю сортировку и первая строка после сортировки и будет нужная цена. Но вот как сказать GROUP BY брать не случайную строку, а именно первую не пойму. Ведь ORDER BY срабатывает после GROUP BY, а мне нужно как то наоборот их отработать

Comment: А нам _надо_ что бы она была определена. Так определите же их. Вы пишите, что хотите минимальную цену, значит сделайте `min(price)` и отсортируйте, уже после join по этому полю, т.е. по минимальной цене

Comment: с MIN я пробовал, но мне ведь нужно учитывать два поля, цену и наличие. И нужны так же остальные поля из строки prices.
т.е. грубо говоря  мне нужно показать товары с самой низкой ценой и самым большим наличием. Один товар может быть у разных поставщиков(несколько записей для товара в таблице prices).

Comment: Если в записи добавить еще наличие, вы хотите запись с максимальным наличием вне зависимости от цены и минимальную цену берете только среди одинаковых наличий ?

Comment: Оно ? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564804/mysql-join-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC/564830#564830

Comment: да, кажется то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Евгений только не `item_id = (select item_id` в таблице prices есть свой уникальный ключ, например price_id тогда будет `price_id = (select price_id ...)` т.е. для данного item_id мы находим уникальный id записи с ценой оказавшейся первой по сортировке и берем именно эту запись

Comment: да, я уже разобрался с этим. Спасибо.