# Присвоить одинаковый флаг идентичным номерам

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, где на выходе получаю номер заказа(неуникальный, равен количеству позиций в заказе) и поле р, которое равно 1, если имя продукта равно "Доставка".

```
    SELECT
    intermediate_beta_post.salesorderid,
    (
        CASE
        WHEN vtiger_products.productname IN ('Доставка') THEN
            1
        ELSE
            0
        END
    ) AS p
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder AS tigr
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON tigr.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
INNER JOIN vtiger_products ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
INNER JOIN integration_betapost.intermediate_beta_post ON tigr.salesorderid = intermediate_beta_post.salesorderid
WHERE
    tigr.salesorderid = intermediate_beta_post.salesorderid
```

[результат](http://joxi.ru/52aZ0Vvt6k3wA0)
Нужно проставлять флаг не только у позиции, значение которой равно Доставка, но и у других позиций в заказе, если одна из них равна Доставке. Т.е. на выходе значение 0 будут иметь только те строки, где ни один salesorderid не равен Доставка.

Comment: Вы думаете не зная структуру таблиц можно ответить на ваш вопрос ? Я вот подозреваю, что можно было бы подзапросом собрать статусы, сгруппировав продукты до заказов. И подклеить результат к основному запросу. Только не знаю как группировать и какие таблицы там должны участвовать, без знания структуры БД это невозможно. И эта "доставка" в таблице products представлена одной записью или их много

Comment: Ну или отсортировать по заказам, но так что бы доставка была первой и с помощью переменных протащить статус на остальные записи, только оно громоздко будет

Comment: @Mike доставка в products одна. Можно пример как с помощью переменных протащить статус на остальные записи(с помощью сортировки можно сделать так,чтобы позиция доставка всегда была первой в списке )

Comment: Ну сортировкой все просто `order by заказ, (productname IN ('Доставка')) desc` (потому что IN на выходе дает 0/1 и 1 нам нужна первой, а 0 потом). А с переменными ... посмотрите например тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/ там правда берется максимум для группы (группа там дата, у вас заказ). а в вашем случае будет `@flag:=if(@заказ=заказ, @flag, productname IN ('Доставка'))`