# Избавиться от подзапросов в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос SQL, проблемная часть которого выглядит так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT chb.ck_filename, 
    ...
    (select gvpl.gvpl_descr
     from gviya gv1, gviya_place gvpl 
     where gv1.gv_gvpl_id = gvpl.gvpl_id
        and gv1.gv_id = (select max(gviya.gv_id)
                         from gviya 
                         where gv_trid = chb.ck_trid
                        )
    ) as gv_place,
    ...
```

Дальше идет выборка остальных полей. Так как в таблице очень много данных, то вложенный запрос выполняется очень долго. Понятно, что он должен выполниться для каждой строчки, то есть, допустим, если основной запрос вернет 1000 строчек, то и вложенный выполнится 1000 раз, увеличивая общее время выполнения в 1000 раз. Надо как-то избавиться от вложенного запроса, при этом все равно получая `gvpl_descr` для `max(gviya.gv_id)` в каждой строчке. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: У вас MySQL? Или MS SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL, но синтаксис же один и тот же. Ну, в данной задаче, мне кажется, одинаковое решение что у того, что у того.

Comment: @Aaron Ну не скажите, в MS SQL можно было бы воспользоваться оконными функциями и/или `cross apply`. А в MySQL переменными (которых нет более ни в одной БД). Так что всегда точно указывайте требуемый диалект SQL, даже на вроде бы простые вещи у каждой БД находятся свои, уникальные, подходы для решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно переписать подзапрос в виде:

```
select gvpl.gvpl_descr
  from gviya gv1, gviya_place gvpl 
 where gv1.gv_gvpl_id = gvpl.gvpl_id
   and gv_trid = chb.ck_trid
 order by gv1.gv_id desc
 limit 1
```

Таким образом мы избавимся от подзапроса второго уровня. Но его выполнение все равно будет достаточно медленным. В идеале надо избавится вообще от подзапросов в списке выборки, например сгруппировав и заранее получив все максимальные gv_id, как предложено в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758554/194569) @Vasil Baymurzin. Но такой подход даст существенный выигрыш только если весь целый запрос выбирает бОльшую часть всех существующих gv_trid. Если это не так, надо смотреть в сторону обеспечения получения уникальных строк всего запроса, а потом подклейки к ним (join) всех подходящих строк gviya с последующей фильтрацией на максимальные с помощью использования переменных или трюков вроде `substr( max( concat() ) )`, как предложено например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569).

В общем для правильной оптимизации, информации, приведенной в вопросе, не достаточно. Необходимо видеть в комплексе весь запрос, всю структуру БД, смотреть планы выполнения и экспериментировать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, можно начать с самого "нижнего" подзапроса, группировать его

```
select max(gviya.gv_id)
from gviya 
group by gv_trid
```

Затем его присоединить к вышестоящему запросу

```
select gvpl.gvpl_descr
from gviya gv1, gviya_place gvpl,
  (select gv_trid, max(gviya.gv_id) max_gv_id
   from gviya 
   group by gv_trid) group_gviya  
where gv1.gv_gvpl_id = gvpl.gvpl_id
  and group_gviya.gv_trid = chb.ck_trid
  and gv1.gv_id = group_gviya.max_gv_id
```

Либо можно, наверное, попробовать как-то воспользоваться оконными функциями