# MySQL GROUP BY и итоговая разница значений

Tags: mysql, group-by

Доброго дня!
В таблице среди прочих имеется поле "rank" (int). И нужно в GROUP BY вывести разницу между первым "rank" в таблице и последним.
То есть не между MAX и MIN, а именно между первой записью и последней.
Как это сделать?
Спасибо.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/373abe

P.S. В навязываемой ссылке на возможный "дубликат" вопроса нет нужного мне оператора MySQL-запроса.

Comment: А что такое "первый" и "последний", в каком порядке, по id ?

Comment: да! Именно так.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/373abe/6

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/373abe/7 - итог. Спасибо, Майк!!!

Comment: Можно в ответе в двух словах об этом написать: substr(max(concat(lpad(id,10,'0'),rank)),11) ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вывод строк с максимальным значением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496515/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: Ничего не понимаю! http://casinocoin.loc/index_n.php

Comment: Сейчас попробую без substr

Comment: substr(max(concat(lpad(id,10,'0'),rank)),11) = substr(min(concat(lpad(id,10,'0'),rank)),11) !!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70721/discussion-on-question-by-choo-hwan-mysql-group-by----).

Comment: http://agroparty.dn.ua/index_n.php - вкладка "Месяц"