# MySQL IF_NULL in WHERE

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, null

Таблица клиентов:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_clients_1_idx` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clients_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companys` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Таблица задач по клиентам:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `deadline` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `client__id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Выводим клиентов:

```
SELECT clients.*, tasks.*
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, task_text, MIN(deadline) as deadline, dt, client_id
    FROM tasks
    WHERE deadline >= NOW()
    GROUP BY client_id
) tasks ON clients.id = tasks.client_id
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN deadline IS NULL THEN "3000:12:12 23:59:59" 
        ELSE deadline
    END ASC,
position ASC, dt DESC
```

Необходимо вывести ближайшую задачу по клиенту (т.е. они могут быть расписаны на неделю вперед, но отображаться должна ближайшая):
MIN(deadline)....WHERE deadline >= NOW()
НО, если при условии WHERE deadline >= NOW() задач нет, нужно отображать последную, которая есть, т.е. без условия: deadline >= NOW()

Comment: *Необходимо вывести ближайшую задачу по клиенту (т.е. они могут быть расписаны на неделю вперед, но отображаться должна ближайшая): MIN(deadline)....WHERE deadline >= NOW() НО, если при условии WHERE deadline >= NOW() задач нет, нужно отображать последную, которая есть, т.е. без условия: deadline >= NOW()* Ну то есть просто последнюю. И незачем накручивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что нибудь в этом роде:

```
SELECT clients.*, tasks.*
  FROM clients
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
      FROM tasks
     WHERE (client_id, deadline) IN(
        SELECT client_id,
               coalesce( MIN(if(deadline >= NOW(), deadline, NULL)), MAX(deadline)) as deadline
          FROM tasks
         GROUP BY client_id
       )
  ) tasks ON clients.id = tasks.client_id
```

При условии, что по одному клиенту не может быть двух задач с одинаковым deadline. Если же они могут быть, то для поиска строки с минимальным/максимальным deadline надо будет воспользоваться [одним из этих подходов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569). Или для MySQL 8.0 воспользоваться нумерацией строк в нужном порядке оконной функцией.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Но клиенты не попадают в выборку, если задачи отсутствуют, несмотря на "LEFT JOIN"

Comment: @YevgeniyM Этот запрос не может приводить к такому эффекту, возможно вы добавили к нему какой нибудь where

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы выводить всех клиентов, даже при отсутствии задачи.

Comment: @YevgeniyM Я понимаю. И этот запрос просто обязан их всех вывести, если вы не добавили к нему какого нибудь where, в котором упоминаются колонки из task (ну или например случайно не заменили ON на where)

Comment: да, where есть, но он там условия по клиенту, например:

SELECT clients.*, tasks.*
  FROM clients
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
      FROM tasks
     WHERE (client_id, deadline) IN(
        SELECT client_id,
               coalesce( MIN(if(deadline >= NOW(), deadline, NULL)), MAX(deadline)) as deadline
          FROM tasks
         GROUP BY client_id
       )
  ) tasks ON clients.id = tasks.client_id
WHERE clients.id=1

Клиент такой есть, задач у него нет. И в выборку не попадает(

Comment: @YevgeniyM Не может оно его не выдавать. приведите пример с данными на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com что бы оно дало такой результат. Оно не выдало бы клиента только если бы вы написали например where tasks.client_id=1

Comment: Да, Вы правы, работает как надо http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da56cf/4
Может дело в версии? У нас 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: @YevgeniyM Дело может быть только в where. добавьте точно свой where там же в sqlfiddle и посмотрите результат

Comment: Похоже, что все-таки дело в марии. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214093
Никак не получается

Comment: @YevgeniyM Этого не может быть. такое поведение left join описано еще в sql92, который соблюдается всеми БД без исключений. А найденная вами статья вообще касается оптимизации, а не поведения запросов. Проверяйте свой код в котором вставлен этот запрос. наверняка там что то в where неправильное добавляется.

Comment: Один и тот же запрос, с одинаковой стуктурой данных, корректно отрабатывается в mysql5.7 и некорректно в mariadb. Может есть какой-то join mode, или что-то подобное?

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Selection_999(182).1545802424.png

Comment: @YevgeniyM Мда, это что то невероятное. Похоже на баг в MariaDB. А если там не подзапрос, а просто left join двух таблиц, поведение такое же ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN без подзапросов отрабатывает как нужно

Comment: @YevgeniyM Чистой воды баг. даже репорт нашел https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14779 там что то в описании сказано про `optimizer_switch='materialization=on'`. Думаю если его поставить в off, то проблема решится. Хотя лучше конечно версию БД менять

Comment: обновимся до 10.3

Comment: Обновление помогло, запрос отработал!