# Выборка из БД последних контактов пользователей

Tags: sql, select, group-by, order-by

Есть таблица связей relations, в которой хранятся id сотрудников, метки времени, когда они взаимодействовали и параметр, который показывает отображать эту связь или нет. Нужно иметь возможность получить все последние исходящие связи одного пользователя с другими уникальными пользователями.

[SQL Fiddle тут](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPYdytrDwqcMihaArVpgwP/3)

Сейчас первый запрос вытаскивает из БД первые контакты пользователей, второй запрос — все контакты упорядоченные по времени от самых свежих к старым. Надо чтобы получался только список самых свежих контактов пользователей.

Читал про помещение в подзапрос ORDER BY, а во внешнем GROUP BY, но такая связка оставляте самую старую связь между пользователями, а не самую свежую.

Comment: `select *` с group by быть не может, потому что * возвращает все колонки исходных записей, а после group by никаких исходных строк в принципе не остается https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599772/194569

Comment: Вам видимо нужно что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496515/194569