# MySQL: оператор WHERE IN и ORDER BY DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Существует таблица **table(timestamp, 'id', 'price')**. В таблице более 20 тыс. строк. Пары не уникальны, обновляются на определенную дату. 
Пример запроса:

```
SELECT `timestamp`, `id`, `price` 
FROM `db`.`table` 
WHERE `id` IN ('id08', 'id54', 'id382' ... т.д.) 
GROUP BY `id` 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC;
```

**Необходимо получить последние цены(price) на последнюю дату(самые свежие) по заданному массиву id.**

Текущий запрос подхватывает `price` первый, что содержится в таблице.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496515/194569

Comment: А версия MySQL какая?

Comment: версия MySQL 5.7

Comment: @Mike там ответы похоже под тяжелой наркотой давали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT `b`.* FROM (SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`, `id` FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `id` IN ('id08', 'id54', 'id382' ... т.д.)  GROUP BY `id`) as `a` LEFT JOIN `db`.`table` as `b` ON `a`.`id`=`b`.`id` AND `a`.`timestamp`=`b`.`timestamp`
```

Comment: В on еще timestamp добавьте и left ни к чему

Comment: Эээ, непонял а зачем там timestamp?

Comment: Он по id сделает join со всеми записями (он же по условиям задачи повторяется) в итоге получим исходную таблицу

Comment: Так мы же сгруппировались по айди, в выборке не будет повторяющихся записей.

Comment: В подзапросе `a` не будет, но в таблице `b` то они есть

Comment: Точно, об этом я не подумал.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Запрос работает. К сожалению очень медленный получился.

Comment: WHERE `id` IN ('id08', 'id54', 'id382' ... т.д.)  будет работать очень медленно, если у вас много элементов.

Comment: Ну и индексы нужно конечно добавить id и timestamp. Но основная причина мне видится во WHERE IN (). Я не знаю откуда берутся у вас эти элементы, если из бд, то от этого надо избалятся заменив на JOIN. Если не из БД, то их можно пометить во временную таблицу и сделать JOIN. Так же айди можно сделать Int, а не Varchar, что будет более оптимально.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответы. Элементы поиска не из БД. На сегодня я сделал перебор полученного массива с БД при помощи php. Функция формирует новый массив со "свежими" timestamp и price с ключом 'id' (поскольку он уникален в таблице). На данный момент работает достаточно быстро, перебор массивов занимает менее 1 сек. Буду еще пробовать со временной таблицей, затем JOIN, как Вы описали. Еще раз большое спасибо!